Shortest Distance Path from a Point on a Sphere to a Great Circle
How can I prove that the shortest path from a point P to a great circle on a sphere is that arc from P to the point Q on the great circle such that arc PQ is perpendicular to the great circle?

This is not exactly right, there are at least two arcs from P to some point Q on the great circle such that PQ is perpendicular to the great circle, and one might be longer. Maybe you want to ask the shortest path is an arc perpendicular to the great circle?

If you know anything about Riemannian geometry, I would recommend you to have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2793667/let-n-subset-m-be-a-submanifold-a-minimizing-geodesic-which-joins-a-point-q .
